# grep a particular string from output

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to grep and print disabled string from below output

```
$ grep "s_icsmstatus" $CONTEXT_FILE
<oa_service_status oa_var="s_icsmstatus">disabled</oa_service_status>
```

I can use something like

```
$ grep "s_icsmstatus" $CONTEXT_FILE | awk -F ">" '{print $(NF-1)}' | awk -F "</" '{print $(NF-1)}'
disabled
```

But is there any alternative simple or straigt way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -o`:

```
grep "s_icsmstatus" $CONTEXT_FILE | grep -o 'disabled'
```

`-o` provides as output `o`nly the exact match for the provided pattern, rather than the entire line in which the match is made.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not the best tool for parsing html tags, but with a little help of `P`erl syntax one can do the following:

```
$ grep -Po 's_icsmstatus">\K[^<]*' $CONTEXT_FILE
disabled
```

the essential part is `\K` which cuts away everything matched so far, and we print only rest, i.e. everything till the next `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, which is a bit more universal as it can grab any word between the XML tags... not just the word 'disabled':

*grep "s_icsmstatus" test.txt | awk -F">" '{print $2}' | awk -F"<" '{print $1}'*

Reference:  http://code.scottshipp.com/2013/06/27/easily-extract-data-from-xml-using-grep-and-awk/